# MongoDB ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members available for replica set name "abc"

Tags: networking, ssh, python, mongodb, vagrant

I'm an experienced programmer, but a Python, Ubuntu, and Linux newbie.  I apologize, as well, if this question would be better in a different forum.

I am working on a project in Python using PyCharm, with code executing in an Ubuntu environment in Vagrant. It has to access a MongoDb database.

When the database is local, I have no difficulties. I also can connect to one remote database.  However, the database I most want to connect to is part of a replica set, and that seems to be the problem.

(I should say that the database with the replica set performs just fine in its actual role.  I seem to be the one with the problem.)

We set up some `ssh` tunnels, using these suggestions:

[Connecting to a Mongo Replica Set via SSH](https://blockdev.io/connecting-to-a-mongo-replica-set-via-ssh/)

We set up `hosts` and `ifconfig` appropriately.

My supervisor can now connect with minimal difficulty.  I, however, keep getting this message:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members available for replica set name "abc"
```

The connection information includes all 3 replica set servers as part of the `host` string, plus the replica set name being specified and `ReadPreference.PRIMARY`.

The stack track looks like this:

```
File "/usr/local/src/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard/app/tasks/exports/__init__.py", line 95, in get_sections
    sections = CourseSection.objects(**params)
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py", line 37, in __get__
    queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection())
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 198, in _get_collection
    cls.ensure_indexes()
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 878, in ensure_indexes
  collection.create_index(fields, background=background, **opts)
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1753, in create_index
    self.__create_index(keys, kwargs, session, **cmd_options)
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1641, in __create_index
    with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 193, in _socket_for_writes
    return self.__database.client._socket_for_writes()
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 965, in _socket_for_writes
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(writable_server_selector)
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 224, in select_server
    address))
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 183, in select_servers
    selector, server_timeout, address)
File "/apps/dashboard-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 199, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members available for replica set name "abc"
```

The specific message `No replica set members available for replica set name "abc"` seems to be relatively uncommon, as I haven't found any hits on Google for problems with a specific named replica set.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are using a wrong replica name. Do u have access to mongodb configuration file?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem.

It turns out that, in order to change what database I run code against, I need to do the following:

1. Kill all `ssh` sessions on Vagrant, to close any existing tunnels.
2. Stop the local `mongod` service:  `service mongod stop`
3. If opening a new tunnel:  execute the desired `ssh` command on Vagrant to create the desired tunnel.  If connecting locally, do nothing.
4. Restart `mongod`:  `service mongod start`

And now my code will connect without errors.

It may be that there's a better way to achieve this, but this allows me to do what I wanted to do.

Comment: Or else you could have selected a different port altogether right?